# java reference to class in action listener

Tags: java, reference, actionlistener

I have JPanel containing two other JPanels inside, gamePanel and OptionsPanel. I want OptionsPanel to contain a button which will trigger a method of gamePanel upon clicking. Is there a better way to do this than just making reference to object in itself? (I want to do `op.getParent.getComponents()` next)

```
class OptionsPanel extends JPanel{
OptionsPanel op = this;

public OptionsPanel(){
    JButton start = new JButton("Rozwiąż sudoku");
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //some code to do
        }
    });
    this.add(start);
}
}
```

here is fragment of a class which contains both gamePanel and OptionsPanel

```
public Sudoku () {
    Dimension ScreenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1000,550) );

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;

    OptionsPanel optionsPanel = new OptionsPanel();
    this.optionsPanel = optionsPanel;

    add(gamePanel);
    add(optionsPanel);
}
```

Comment: I don't see your `gamePanel` - would you be able to include the code for that? Is `gamePanel` an object within `OptionsPanel` or a class?  Please provide more information and code.

Comment: I have JPanel which contains both gamePanel and OptionsPanel;

Comment: You already said that in your post, but didn't further specify. Please provide more information and code.

Comment: Ok, you've included code in a comment.  Please edit your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: i mean this is working but im not sure if its right way to do this

Answer (score 0):

---

### Java 8

---

Because [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) extends [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), it can be named using [`Component#setName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)). I would give gamePanel a custom name so that it is identifiable in an array. For eaxmple, your gamePanel constructor might look like:

```
public GamePanel() {
    this.setName("gamePanel");
}
```

And you could single it out using that name:

```
start.addActionListener(e -> java.util.Arrays.stream(op.getComponents()).forEach(c -> {
    if (c.getName().equals("gamePanel")) {
        ((GamePanel) c).method();
    }
}));
```

---

### Java 7

---

If you cannot use  the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) API or lambda expressions, you can simply use a for loop:

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < op.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component c = op.getComponent(i);
            if (c.getName().equals("gamePanel")) {
                ((GamePanel) c).method();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

### Other

---

There is one more approach that is a lot more efficient and less messy. You could include a `GamePanel` parameter in the  `OptionsPanel` constructor and pass your gamepanel to that:

```
public OptionsPanel(GamePanel gamePanel){
    JButton start = new JButton("Rozwiąż sudoku");
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gamePanel.method();
        }
    });
    this.add(start);
}
```

Then all you need to do is change how you construct  your optionsPanel instance:

```
public Sudoku () {
    Dimension ScreenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1000,550) );

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;

    // Pass your GamePanel instance to the constructor.
    OptionsPanel optionsPanel = new OptionsPanel(gamePanel);
    this.optionsPanel = optionsPanel;

    add(gamePanel);
    add(optionsPanel);
}
```

Comment: when i want to use this inside constructor of ActionListener "this" refers to actionListener.

Comment: A third way is quite a bit more involved: it uses events, where upon clicking the button a specific event type is created and fired into some transmission media, where the other listeners are also selected. The interested party subscrives to event transmitted via this media and receives the event when that happens. There can be more than one subscriber to said event, and whoever fires it doesn't need to care about who is interested in catching the thing.

Comment: I do love the observer pattern. @M.Prokhorov is explaining this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm - it is likely the most reusable and robust, and is also more efficient than looping through each panel. Passing in as a parameter is my second favourite most of the time, but could be my favourite if the observer patter doesn't make sense, and would never make sense for this down the road.

Comment: @adpro, that example is mostly fine, but it leaks unfinished observer objects from constructors, which makes this implementation thread-unsafe. And I myself prefer the kind of `update` method on observer which receives the "gist" object describing what kind of update happened. In short, more along the lines of [Spring events](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

Comment: I didn't look through my example that closely, but thanks for pointing that specific example's shortcomings.